# WSO2 ESB can not extract a soap element value

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm not able to fetch value of **clinicID** from following soap envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id>
            <tfom:clinicID>6048820</tfom:clinicID>
         </tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<property xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms"
                   name="CLINIC_ID"
                   expression="//clinicID/text()"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

This is how I log value of **CLINIC_ID**:

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="1" expression="get-property('CLINIC_ID')"/>
</log>
```

And this is value of **CLINIC_ID**:

> 1 = null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with your xpath expression. If you use

```
<property xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms"
                   name="CLINIC_ID"
                   expression="//tfom:clinicID/text()"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

it should work. Missing part is the namespace prefix in the expression.

You can try the xpath expression's accuracy by using a online tool such as http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

I did use it and was able to get the clinicID value as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $body synapse xpath variable to access body of the payload. So for the expression for property mediator would be

$body/tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id/tfom:clinicID/test()

Comment: i can't use it. because in this proxy i have more than one payload where in arg's in payloads i use this property  like this :  get-property('CLINIC_ID')  or  $axis2:CLINIC_ID

Comment: for example:    for this soap i cant catch clinicID <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <tfom:get_inserted_liks_division_to_bed>
                        <tfom:clinicID>$1</tfom:clinicID>
                     </tfom:get_inserted_liks_division_to_bed>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: OK. What I meant was to define a property using this expression. Ex:
<property xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms"
                   name="CLINIC_ID"
                   expression="$body/tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id/tfom:clinicID/test()"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>

And then use that property

Comment: TID[-1234] [ESB] [2016-06-03 14:25:00,134] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.PropertyMediatorFactory} - Invalid XPath expression for attribute &#x27;expression&#x27; : $body/tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id/tfom:clinicID/test()

Comment: i can do like this     `<property xmlns:tfom="https://bur.cdmarf.ru/dss/services/tfoms"
                   name="CLINIC_ID"
                   expression="//tfom:get_single_inserted_branch_by_id/tfom:clinicID"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="1" expression="get-property('CLINIC_ID')"/>
         </log> `  but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Thank you Tishan. I have another question about wso2 esb with rabbitMQ. I think to post it now

Answer (score 0):

If your sending request like in below format

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.samples" xmlns:xsd="http://services.samples/xsd">  
    <soapenv:Header/>  
     <soapenv:Body>  
       <ser:getQuote>  
     <!--Optional:-->  
       <ser:request>  
     <!--Optional:-->  
   <xsd:symbol>wso2</xsd:symbol>  
  </ser:request>  
</ser:getQuote>
```

you need to write a proxy

```
         <property xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd"
               xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
               name="symbol"
               expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m1:symbol"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
               name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
               expression="fn:concat('?symbol=',get-property('symbol1'))"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
```

For more details please refer [here](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-conver-http-post-request-to-http.html) or [here](http://wso2experience.blogspot.com/2015/10/simple-wso2-esb-ejb-mediator.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<property name="CLINIC_ID" expression="//*[local-name()='clinicID']/text()" type="STRING" scope="default"/>
```